# How to Write a jest test by mocking Axios, using the action provided?

Tags: reactjs, testing, mocking, jestjs, axios

I am new to testing using jest and I am stuck on how I can test this piece of code given to show that Axios.post is called when my registerUser is called. I have searched online and don't have a solid solution to post. Would be grateful if a solution could be provided

This is the function I need to test from authAction.js

```
export const registerUser = (userData, history) => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/users/register", userData)
    .then(res => history.push("/login")) // re-direct to login on successful register
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      })
    );
};
```

I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
import * as authActions from './authActions';
import axios from 'axios';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'; //ES6 modules
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
const middleware = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureStore(middleware);


describe('test register user axios', () => {
    it('should give a response of 201 back after it registers user', () => {


        var userData = {email: "kamara@fc.come",
        name: "Kris Kamara",
        password: "adam123",
        password2: "adam123"
        }

        var history = jest.fn();

        const initialState = {}
        const store = mockStore(initialState)

        store.dispatch(authActions.registerUser({userData}, history));
        expect(axios).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    });
  });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

Return the `Promise` from the function like this:

```js
export const registerUser = (userData, history) => dispatch => {
  return axios  // <= return the Promise
    .post("/api/users/register", userData)
    .then(res => history.push("/login")) // re-direct to login on successful register
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      })
    );
};
```

...and then you can test it like this:

```js
import * as authActions from './authActions';
import axios from 'axios';

describe('registerUser', () => {

  let mock;
  beforeEach(() => {
    mock = jest.spyOn(axios, 'post');
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    mock.mockRestore();
  });

  it('should register the user and redirect to login', async () => {
    const push = jest.fn();
    const history = { push };
    const dispatch = jest.fn();
    mock.mockResolvedValue();  // mock axios.post to resolve

    await authActions.registerUser('the user data', history)(dispatch);

    expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/api/users/register', 'the user data');  // Success!
    expect(history.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/login');  // Success!
  });
});
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks so much for your help.!!!!! Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear!  @JohnSmith

Comment: ...also, friendly reminder to upvote answers that are helpful, and mark as accepted answers that solve the issue @JohnSmith

Answer (score -1):

```
export const addOrganizationsData = (params) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(showSpinner());
  return interceptor
    .post(`/api/v1/organizations`, params)
    .then(({ data }) => {
      dispatch(actionTypes.saveOrganization(data));
      dispatch(closeSpinner());
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch(actionTypes.organizationsError(err));
      dispatch(closeSpinner());
    });
};
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question. What do you want to do with this code snippet ?